# When we use a PRF to pad a message, do we need to worry about the PRF's output range and/or probability of collision?

Tags: encryption, collision-resistance, pseudo-random-function, padding

My question is related to:

1. [How to contruct a pseudorandom with a specific property](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43463/how-to-contruct-a-pseudorandom-with-a-specific-property)
2. [Collision in pseudorandom function when two different keys are used](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43452/collision-in-pseudorandom-function-when-two-different-keys-are-used)

**Question**: When we use a pseudorandom function to pad a message do we need to worry about the pseudorandom function's output range and the probability of collision?

Assume we blind (read: *“add padding to”*) a message $m$ as $r_1=m\cdot PRF(k,1)$, and next time we blind it as $r_2=m\cdot PRF(k',1)$, where $k,k'$ are two independent random keys. We give $r_1,r_2$ to an adversary.

If our PRF is not collision resistant then when $PRF(k,1)=PRF(k',1)$ then the adversary can learn the message $m$.

Comment: If the condition $PRF(k,1) = PRF(k',1)$ happens no more often than would be expected for a random function, that is, if it happens with probability $2^{-n}$, where the length of the PRF output is $n$ bits, then this is a nonissue

Comment: @poncho thank you for the comment. My question is then, why do we have the notion of collision-resistant PRF in the literature. see : http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/866/chp%253A10.1007%252F3-540-48910-X_30.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fchapter%2F10.1007%2F3-540-48910-X_30&token2=exp=1485959209~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F866%2Fchp%25253A10.1007%25252F3-540-48910-X_30.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Fchapter%252F10.1007%252F3-540-48910-X_30*~hmac=4157c370f0b835e6e790f60d3e997e76cc93fcf501a440639db62ccd7790132c